# How to transform Spec-flow table into dictionary?

Tags: c#, testing, automation, automated-tests, specflow

This is the scenario:

```
   Given the text and the following fields:
  | text  | field   |
  | text1 | field1  |
```

I want to iterate both of this for them to use in one generic method, so in the future fill a form, per example, just by using this scenario

The method:

```cs
     public void ThenIEnterInTheField(Table table)
    var texts = table.Rows.Select(row => int.Parse(row["text "]));

    foreach (var text in texts)
    {
        input(text, field);
    }
```

But I have no idea how to do this in the best way as possible to iterate both or something like that, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [anonymous object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) with required properties and iterate over it.

```
var texts = table.Rows
              .Select(row => new { Text = int.Parse(row["text"]), Field = row["field"]});

foreach (var text in texts)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Text : {text.Text} and Field : {text.Field}");
    input(text.Text, text.Field);
}
```

Comment: thank you! I'm using this and everything goes perfect, this is what exactly what I need